# Add syntax highlighting for the matlab tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Please add syntax highlighting to the [matlab](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab) tag.

From [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) :

> Only moderators can change the highlighting language for a tag.

`lang-matlab` is one of the supported languages for syntax highlighting.

I manually added the `matlab` language hint to the code block when I edited this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/635682/confusion-regarding-transfer-function-and-state-space-conversion-in-matlab).  However, it would be much more convenient to have the syntax highlighting automatically applied to code blocks for this tag.

Comment: Note: OP removed the language hint you added, after your edit. Not sure why.

Comment: @dim: Thanks for the note.  The OP replaced the original code with new code after my edit.  It's possible the OP did not notice the hint or didn't know what it was for.  This is yet another reason to enable automated highlighting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good idea. I've set the language for the tag.